# Definition functions, integrals on $\mathbb R^{|N|}, \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Is there a standard/reasonable way of defining functions on the sets $\mathbb R^{|\mathbb N|}, \mathbb R^{\mathbb R} $. How about defining integrals over these sets? I guess a function on $\mathbb R^{|\mathbb N|}$ could assign to an $\mathbb N$-ple its sum, maybe its product; what types, if any, of functions are usually defined in these sets? How about Riemann/Lebesgue integration, do we define a limiting process on $\int_\infty^\infty \int_\infty^\infty\cdots$.
Thanks.

EDIT: From the input, I realized that some examples of this from functional analysis are operators on function spaces. For countably-dimensional spaces we could have, e.g., operators on $l^2$, for uncountably-dimensional spaces, we could have, e.g., operators on $C[a,b]$. But I cannot figure out how to integrate over either $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ or over $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Sorry, avid19, my computer conked out and then I was unable to log in to chat with you. Could we please chat some other time?

Comment: Functions *to* what set? It seems like $\Bbb R$ is being implied?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking $\mathbb R$, but it would be great if it could be more general.